# Adding to an Array function in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to add an array to an array of Double arrays in a for loop.  Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Test3()
 Dim a() As Double, i As Integer
 ReDim a(1 To 10, 1 To 3)

 Dim d

 For i = 1 To 3
  d = Array(a)
 Next i

End Sub
```

In this test I'm just trying to add 3 copies of 'a' into 'd'.  I have d = Array(a) which of course doesn't work, but I don't know what line to replace it with

Edited code for clarity

New Code Attempt:

```
Sub Test3()
 Dim a() As Double, i As Integer
 ReDim a(1 To 10, 1 To 3)
 a(1, 2) = 3.5

 Dim d() As Variant

 For i = 1 To 3
  ReDim Preserve d(1 To i)
  d(i) = Array(a)
 Next i


 Dim x() As Double
 x = d(1)   ' Error, Type Mismatch

 MsgBox (x(1, 2))

End Sub
```

I get the error of a type mismatch on x = d(1)

Comment: d = d + Array(a)   ?
What are you trying to do?
It is very difficult to tell what you are trying to do, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Sorry, this is just test code with extra stuff in it. I am trying to get 3 copies of a() into d as an array of objects.  I tried that line and it doesn't work.  I edited the code to more concisely show what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want what's called a "Jagged Array", or Array of Arrays

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim a() As Double, b() As Double, c() As Double, i As Integer

    ReDim a(1 To 10, 1 To 3)
    ReDim b(1 To 2, 1 To 4)
    ReDim c(1 To 5, 1 To 11)

    a(1, 2) = 3.5
    b(1, 2) = 2.5

    Dim d As Variant
    ReDim d(1 To 6)

    ' Add 3 copies of a to d
    For i = 1 To 3
     d(i) = a
    Next i

    ' add other arrays to d
    d(4) = b
    d(5) = c

    ' Access elements of d
    Dim x() As Double
    x = d(1)

    MsgBox x(1, 2)
    MsgBox d(1)(1, 2)
    MsgBox d(4)(1, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting an error.  Please see my edits of the op

Comment: Why did you not follow the example I gave you? `d(i) = Array(a)` creates an Array of Arrays of Arrays.  With your code, you would need to write `x = d(1)(0)` to access the inner most array.  Examine your varibles in the watch window to see what I mean.